# Setting Isolation level in a database / table

Tags: mysql, isolation-level

I understand the concept of isolation w.r.t transactions.
I want to know whether I can set the default isolation level for the entire database / a particular table in a database.

I want to do this because i understand that increasing the isolation level can impact performance so i want to restrict the change to a few tables in the entire DB.

Comment: Assuming you could set the default isolation level per table, and you did a query that joined two tables with different defaults, which isolation level do you suppose it would use?

Comment: If you are doing thousands of transactions _per second_, isolation levels _may_ need tuning.  Otherwise, your question comes under the category of "premature optimization".  That is, don't worry about isolation level until you have a specific use case.  Even then, there may be a workaround to avoid the performance issue without touching "isolation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the transaction isolation level for a session. Or for the server. But not for one table.

As a workaround, you can set the desired isolation level immediately before you operate on that single table. Just stay aware that you've set the isolation level for your session.

[Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#:%7E:text=InnoDB%20offers%20all%20four%20transaction,%2C%20REPEATABLE%20READ%20%2C%20and%20SERIALIZABLE%20.)

> i understand that increasing the isolation level can impact performance

Have you measured the impact?

Comment: It's worth noting that if one changes the tx isolation, do it _before_ starting the transaction. I've been surprised how many times I've seen code that changes the tx isolation after starting the transaction, and the developer was confused why it had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a database eg. Mysql that support multiple engine, then you can create your special table with a special engine eg. memory.

Then your query can fetch rows from most tables with the isolation level of current session, and fetch rows from the special table with the only isolation level for the special engine.

It is not a general solution for your problem, but it may help in some cases.